# Java манипуляции с битами

Tags: java

Я задавал этот вопрос на Stackoverflow и мне вроде бы даже очень подробно ответили, но к сожалению моего английского не хватает для того, чтобы разобраться с хитрой битовой магией джавы. Если не трудно, то мог бы кто-нибудь объяснить в целом по-русски что, как и где. Премного благодарен

[похожий вопрос с ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563544/java-bit-manipulation)
[мой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435401/java-bit-unsigned-shifting-give-strange-result)

Comment: выучите для начала английский, хотя бы в степени достаточной для того чтобы понимать ответы которые вам дают на Stackoverflow.

Comment: В таком случае для чего существует этот клон stackoverflow? Может вы еще посоветуете сначала на лингвиста выучиться? Я достаточно понимаю  английский для того чтобы разбираться в коде,но в данном вопросе слишком много теории.
P.S. как всегда на отечественных форумах готовы обосрать кого угодно и делать что угодно, кроме непосредственно помощи. чванливость русскоязычного сообщества зашкаливает.

Comment: Проблема в объеме информации и сложности. понимание общего тона предложения не дает понимания важных деталей. потому и попросил помощи здесь. но как всегда вместо слов по делу, каждый считает своим долгом проходя мимо указывать как лучше жить или отвечать вопросом на вопрос. в конце концов тема не настолько примитивная и довольно интересная чтобы ответ на нее помог тем кто не сможет вопрос на английском задать.

Comment: >В таком случае для чего существует этот клон stackoverflow? 

@mechanikos согласитесь, он всё-таки существует явно не затем чтобы переводить ответы со stackoverflow. Это я к тому, что наиболее разумным было бы все же помимо ссылок выложить и содержимое самого вопроса

Comment: @mechanikos, если хотите получать хорошие ответы, то потрудитесь задавать хорошие вопросы (**четко** сформулированные на **русском** языке и по возможности без  отсылок на другие страницы).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@mechanikos](/users/18171/mechanikos)](/users/18171/mechanikos) смотрите. Ваш код таков (приведу его тут для наглядности):

```
int i = 255;
byte b = (byte) i;
int c;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString( i));
System.out.println("b = " + b); // b = -1
c=b>>>1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString( c));
System.out.println(c);
```

Дело в том, что byte - знаковый тип с диапазоном -128..127. это может показаться несколько неожиданным, поскольку логично ожидать, что байт содержит значения  от 0 до 255 (скажем, в C# это именно так) Впрочем, неважно. Важно то, что приводя **int** со значение 255 к **byte** вы не получите в переменной **b** ожидаемого значения **255**, а получите -1, поскольку в дополнительном коде -1 в однобайтовой переменной будет представлять собой 8 единиц. Судя по вашему коду, вы это заметили. Так вот далее вы применяете к этому байту беззнаковый сдвиг вправо, который по сути и является "настоящим" сдвигом в отличие от >>, поскольку заполняет левые биты  нулями. В итоге, сдвинув число вправо на один бит, вы получаете младший бит равным нулю, отчего число уже не является отрицательным, поскольку левый бит у него обнулен.

А вот если бы вы выполняли сдвиг по отношению к с, то результат был бы ожидаемым, так как никакого переполнения при приведении не было бы (как впрочем и самого приведения):

```
System.out.println(i >>> 1);
```

Comment: спасибо, за ответ. но там больше всего проблем именно из за приведения типов. эксперементальным путем и насилованием мозга джвадоками вроде понял. как  разберусь, попробую на хабр чтоль статью кинуть,думаю тема полезная и не затеряется как посты в разных блогах

Comment: >думаю тема полезная

Ну это всего лишь хранение отрицательных чисел в дополнительном коде) На самом деле тема не настолько интересна, как вам кажется, поскольку алгоритм этих преобразований  укладывается буквально в два коротких шага. Почитайте например [тут][1]

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: тем не менее эта дрянь мне вторые сутки мозг выносит. ужель я столь туп и все остальные так легко с этим разобрались?(((((( а все началось с реализации регистра сдвига на java...

Comment: в принципе, если я правильно понял, то для того чтобы работало все как я ожидал и вообще иметь вохможость работать с интервалом от 0 до 255 в byte, то нужно просто всегда использовать маску 0хFF и будет цаца

Comment: >чтобы работало все как я ожидал и вообще иметь вохможость работать с интервалом от 0 до 255 в byte, то нужно просто всегда использовать маску 0хFF

я не работаю с Java, и честно говоря, не знаю, как там избегают проблем с отсутствием беззнаковых типов (а их там нет), однако думаю, что если вам нужны значения от 0 до 255, то логично было бы использовать тип данных, который включает в себя этот диапазон

Comment: "с отсутствием беззнаковых типов (а их там нет)" -есть char-он беззнаковый.
 а вообще сам знаю, что костыли, но есть идиотские требования использовать в качетсве регистра однобайтовую целочисленную беззнаковую переменную. можно было бы написать все на С#, но я решил учить жабу и потому вот и топчусь по граблям

Comment: >но есть идиотские требования использовать в качетсве регистра однобайтовую целочисленную беззнаковую переменную

ну тогда остается юзать маски или, если позволяют идиотские требования, написать свой тип данных, удовлетворяющий этим требованиям